# How to add JQuery to a Joomla 3 page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I am new to Joomla 3.

I am trying to add a JQuery script to a joomla page that runs with the $ sign. 
In the [documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aJavascript_Frameworks#jQuery_JavaScript_Framework), I found that I need to add `JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);` to do that, but it isn't working.

I tried:

```
<?php 

JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);

?>

<div class="text">JQuery is not working</div> 

<script type=text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.text').text("JQUERY ROCKS!");

});
</script>
```

And the usual:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    

<div class="text">JQuery is not working</div> 

<script type=text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.text').text("JQUERY ROCKS!");

});
</script>
```

But none works. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your loading jQuery without no conflict mode.  Joomla uses another JavaScript library Mootools which also used the $ symbol, which is why it isn't working. I would change your call to:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
```

And you could either use jQuery instead of $ for all your jQuery methods or wrap your existing code around an Immediately Invoked Function like so:

```
(function ($) {

     // put your jQuery code here that used $

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to use the $ sign since I have an application with a lot of JQuery in it that is using $. I tried your suggestion, but still it doesn't work.